# Hashtag character in JavaScript routing libraries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I sometimes see some web applications in production with this below routing pattern : `{HOST}/#/{ENDPOINT}`, in Angular applications, but this's not opiniated to one library.

What is/are the benefit/s of using the character `#` in routes?

Comment: The hashtag in the URL means we’re telling the browser to stay on the same page and whatever comes afterword is basically disregarded by the browser. Full article here: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-AngularJS-links-have-a-hashtag-What-is-its-purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hashRouter is normally used when you're not sure if your server supports pushState and you want the ability to move between routes within your application and keep the UI in sync. This is also used if you want to support browsers that don't support pushState.

Everything after the hash will be matched to your routing library.